# Flutter - setState to another class

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I just started programming in Flutter. I want to create an app to keep track of the expiration dates of food.
My app is composed of:

- main.dart that returns a MaterialApp class with inside the Home
- home.dart that contains the AppBar, a Scaffold which contains a ListBuilder() as body and a FAB which should add a new item.
- list_builder.dart that contains the stateful widget ListBuilder which takes a list of Strings from items_list.dart and creates a ListView with some tiles
- items_list.dart that contains a List of Strings, a function to remove, add and retrieve the list.

What I made so far is a list of items with a trailing trash icon button that deletes the single item from the list. All works as expected.
Now I want that pressing the FAB, it triggers the ItemsList.addItem() which adds an item to the list. That works, of course, but the list on screen (created by the list_builder.dart) is not updated unless I delete one item.

I tried unsuccessfully to use callback functions, I'm sure I'm missing something.

This is the code:

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'home.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Quando Scade?',
      home: Home(),
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.lightGreen,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**home.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quando_scade/items_list.dart';

import 'list_builder.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Quando Scade?'),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
      ),
      body: ListBuilder(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          ItemsList.addItem('ciao');
          print('item added!!!');
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**list_builder.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'items_list.dart';

class ListBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListBuilder({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListBuilderState createState() => _ListBuilderState();
}

class _ListBuilderState extends State<ListBuilder> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: ItemsList.getItems().length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return _buildRow(ItemsList.getItems()[index], index);
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildRow(String item, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        item,
      ),
      trailing: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            ItemsList.removeItem(index);
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**items_list.dart**

```
class ItemsList {
  static List<String> _items = [
    'banane',
    'latte',
    'caffè',
    'vino',
    'sushi',
    'birra',
  ];

  // to add items
  static void addItem(String name) => ItemsList._items.add(name);

  // to remove item
  static void removeItem(int i) => ItemsList._items.removeAt(i);

  // returns the list of items
  static List<String> getItems() {
    return ItemsList._items;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using `setState` on item delete, you should use it when adding an item as well:

```
...
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      ItemsList.addItem('ciao');
    });
    
    print('item added!!!');
  },
  child: const Icon(Icons.add),
),
...
```

Of course, make the `Home` widget as `StatefulWidget` before that.

Comment: While this might work, it's not a good idea to always rebuild the entire widget tree just to update a list.

Comment: Well, if const constructor would be used for the `ListBuilder` widget, that won’t be such a huge problem. In general, agree, state management is used for what OP is trying to do, I am not saying that’s a good solution, but for this specific case, `setState` would work.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is not an optimal solution to what you're looking for, however, it's better than changing your `Home` class to a stateful widget and rebuilding your entire widget tree. I have modified your code to make it work exactly the way you want it without calling the `setState` function.

**home.dart**

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Quando Scade?'),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
      ),
      body: ListBuilder(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          ItemsList.itemList.addItem('ciao');
          print('item added!!!');
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**items_list.dart**

```
class ItemsList {
  final _list = [
    'banane',
    'latte',
    'caffè',
    'vino',
    'sushi',
    'birra',
  ];

  StreamController<List<String>> _items =
      StreamController<List<String>>.broadcast();

  Stream<List<String>> get items => _items.stream;

  // to add items
  void addItem(String name) {
    //_reOpenStream();
    _list.add(name);
    _items.sink.add(_list);
    // _items.close();
  }

  // to remove item
  void removeItem(int i) {
    //_reOpenStream();
    _list.removeWhere((element) => element == _list[i]);
    _items.sink.add(_list);
  }

  void close() {
    _items.close();
  }

  static final ItemsList _singleton = ItemsList._internal();

  static ItemsList get itemList => ItemsList();

  factory ItemsList() {
    return _singleton;
  }

  ItemsList._internal();
}
```

**list_builder.dart**

```
class ListBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListBuilder({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListBuilderState createState() => _ListBuilderState();
}

class _ListBuilderState extends State<ListBuilder> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<String>>(builder: (_, snapshot) {
      int itemCount = snapshot.data.length;
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: itemCount,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          //Handle the empty list by replacing the container widget with your logic
          return itemCount <=0 ? Container(): _buildRow(snapshot.data[index], index);
        },
      );
    }, initialData: [],);
  }

  Widget _buildRow(String item, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        item,
      ),
      trailing: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            ItemsList.itemList.removeItem(index);
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Only call the `close()` method when you no longer need the stream, otherwise, it'd throw a `bad state` error when you try accessing it again. Additionally, as you progress in your learning try refactoring your codes to use an architecture design.. Peace!

Comment: "_list.removeWhere((element) => element == _list[i]);" ... are you afraid of "removeAt"?

Comment: Lol...No, I'm not afraid of using the `removeAt` function. I was trying to provide a solution that won't require the OP to change much of his codes.

Comment: @OGx09 Well, since this is a fresh project with just a few lines of code, I would be happy to hear from you any suggestion on how I can improve the code.